# SharePoint Randomly Adding Code nbsp

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript, html, angularjs

So just now, I had a bug in my site that caused my custom navigation bar's buttons to be sized and spaced incorrectly. I had no idea where this bug came from, and had to search around for awhile to find the answer. It turns out that SharePoint decided it would be a good idea to inexplicably add a few lines of:

```
nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;

nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;
```

between my   in my DevHome.aspx (I'm using Angular for this particular project). So, why does Sharepoint do this, and how do I prevent it? This is not the first time SharePoint has randomly added an nbsp to my page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to explain where the code originates from. First guess would be it came from a line-break in a (text)editor

Comment: You should remove space and break lines in your code and then try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid invisible characters wiki numbered and bullet lists SharePoint 16.0.0.4508](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159966/how-to-avoid-invisible-characters-wiki-numbered-and-bullet-lists-sharepoint-16-0)

Comment: Where can I find that numeric 8203. I couldn't find it from SP designer. Help me in resolving.
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8o5j.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8o5j.png) Advance Thankyou. Regards
Gowtham

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the finicky behavior of sharepoint designer--it's really nothing you are doing wrong, or anyway you can stop it. Use another dev tool (like Visual Studios Code) and update it using WEBDAV. Make sure you check it out if it has content approval on for the library.

Comment: Easy with a tool like [gulp-spsync](https://github.com/wictorwilen/gulp-spsync)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I provided here: 
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/162319/47986

Note that I'm still seeing this problem with Chrome 71.

The problem seems to be caused by using Chrome 46 to edit the SharePoint lists.  If the page is created and maintained with IE 11, I'm not seeing the problem.

Once I found out the problem involves the `&#8023` / U+200B Unicode character 'Zero Width Space'.  Googling turned up some useful search results...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205193/javascript-remove-zero-width-space-unicode-8203-from-string.

This appears to be some kind of defect in Microsoft SharePoint's RichText field.

The only workaround I've found so far is to manually remove the character using this process:

1. Use Chrome.
2. Access the wiki page with 8203 / U+200B.
3. Edit the wiki page.
4. CTRL+F to search for the text afflicted with 8203 / U+200B.
5. Press F2 to edit the text.
6. While carefully preserving the "" (quotation marks) surrounding the 8203 and the text, delete only the `&#8203;` unicode character 'Zero Width Space'.
7. Save the page.

Comment: This answer is the exact same one as (this one)[https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/158094/content-nbsp-is-adding-to-the-pages/255297#255297]. Either the questions are equal and shoudl be merged, or they are different and should have different answers. Don't you think?

Comment: @4rchit3ct Agreed.  I've flagged this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @4rchit3ct The question [https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/158094/content-nbsp-is-adding-to-the-pages/255297#255297] you referenced does appear to be a duplicate of this question.  In contrast, I realized my question involves slightly different invisible character that SharePoint isadding is zero width space U+200B / (HTML &#8203;) not a nbsp / U+00A0 (HTML &#160;).  So this question is related but not really a duplicate of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Internet Explorer. I was able to edit my page without having extra invisible spaces or `<br>`'s added. Huzzah.